# Execute a kivy Script on start up of the raspberry

Tags: raspberry-pi, kivy, sh, raspbian

I would like to execute a python script launching a kivy App at the start up of the Raspberry pi. One little particularity is that I use a workaround to launch my kivy app (see [this thread](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/3913) on kivy's github and especially, [this response](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/3913#issuecomment-275912204))

My script is really basic as you can see (and it's working) :

```
#!/bin/sh

./kivyrun /home/pi/Desktop/interfacebancdetest_dev/main.py
```

### What I already tried

I followed [this tutorial](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-run-a-raspberry-pi-program-on-startup#method-2-autostart), and created an `"LPBM.desktop"` to `/home/pi/.config/autostart/`

#### my script

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=LPBM
Exec=/home/pi/Desktop/LPBM.sh
```

but it didn't work...

I also tried to modify my `/etc/rc.local`and I added `/home/pi/Desktop/LPBM.sh`before the `exit 0` but once again it didn't work either so i'm little bit stuck...

Comment: if you run `which kivyrun` it will hopefully tell you the absolute path to where kivyrun is on the system. can you try to add `@/absolute/path/to/kivyrun /home/pi/Desktop/interfacebancdetest_dev/main.py` in the autostart file (`~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`) directly (replacing`/absolute/path/to/` with what you got back from `which kivyrun`) ?

Comment: Great stuff! I've just added my comment as an answer: feel free to up-vote it and mark it as an answer. Thank you and good luck with your project

Comment: thank you so much @GeorgeProfenza it worked ! Is there a way to mark your comment as an answer ? 
One last question, the next step is to turn off the raspberry when i'm leaving my kivy app, with something like : `subprocess.call('halt')` but I would need to be a superuser in this case... Is there a way to execute my python script like this ? 
(I tried to add `sudo @/absolute/path/to/kivyrun /home/pi/Desktop/interfacebancdetest_dev/main.py` in the autostart file, and the app started, but te tactile screen was frozen

Comment: I haven't used `halt` myself, but you're bang on the buck using sudo, just note it should be `@sudo /asolute/path/...`. I would also try `subprocess.call(['shutdown','-h,'now'])`. I remember having an issue with that and having to make a copy of the shutdown command because of priviledge issue. Please post another question so we don't make these comments too long and I'll gladly supply the workaround I've used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to start your script directly from the autostart file.

One thing to bare in mind is that the autostart location may be different depending on what user you're logged in as. For example, with a default Raspian install the local path for the LXDE desktop environment autostart file currently would be:

```
~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

If you add an entry prefixed with `@` it should launch the script for you. 
In my experience the using absolute paths were most stable.

In your case you're locally calling `./kivyrun`, but you can use `which kivyrun` to find out where it's installed. After that all that's left is to point `kivyrun` to your script, for example:

```
@/absolute/path/to/kivyrun /home/pi/Desktop/interfacebancdetest_dev/main.py
```

Where `/absolute/path/to/` would get swapped out with the absolute path returned by `which kivyrun` previously